# AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'pathname2url'

Tags: python, module, path, attributeerror, python-3.9

I am using `python 3.9.16` with `robot 3.1.2` and `urllib3`.

Below packages and version is used, and I got `Error: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'pathname2url'`

I am stuck , can any one help to solve this problem?

```
Package                                Version
-------------------------------------- ----------
attrs                                  21.4.0
bcrypt                                 3.2.2
certifi                                2023.11.17
cffi                                   1.14.3
chardet                                3.0.4
cryptography                           3.3.1
cx-Oracle                              8.3.0
et-xmlfile                             1.1.0
idna                                   2.10
importlib-metadata                     4.8.3
jsonref                                1.1.0
jsonschema                             2.6.0
natsort                                8.4.0
oauthlib                               3.2.2
openpyxl                               3.1.2
paramiko                               3.3.1
pip                                    20.2.4
ply                                    3.11
py4j                                   0.10.9.7
pycparser                              2.20
PyNaCl                                 1.5.0
pyrsistent                             0.18.0
PySocks                                1.7.1
requests                               2.25.0
requests-oauthlib                      1.3.1
robot                                  20071211
robotframework                         3.1.2
robotframework-databaselibrary         1.2.4
robotframework-docker                  0.1.0
robotframework-excellib                2.0.1
robotframework-extendedrequestslibrary 0.5.5
robotframework-httplibrary             0.4.2
robotframework-pabot                   0.96
robotframework-pythonlibcore           3.0.0
robotframework-requests                0.6.2
robotframework-ride                    1.7.4
robotframework-selenium2library        3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary         4.1.0
robotframework-soaplibrary             0.8
robotframework-sshlibrary              3.8.0
robotframework-stacktrace              0.4.1
robotframework-suds2library            1.0
robotframework-sudslibrary-aljcalandra 1.1.4
robotframework-sudslibrary3            1.0
robotremoteserver                      1.1.1
scp                                    0.14.5
selenium                               4.15.2
setuptools                             50.3.2
six                                    1.11.0
suds-bis                               1.0.0
suds-jurko                             0.6
suds-py3                               1.4.5.0
urllib3                                1.21.1
wxPython                               4.2.1
xlrd                                   2.0.1
xlrd2                                  1.3.4
xlutils                                2.0.0
xlwt                                   1.3.0
zipp                                   3.6.0
```

Trying to execute robot testcases

Comment: copied below and solved

 pathname2url
[ site-packages]$ pwd
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
[automation@ site-packages]$ sudo cp -r Suds2Library SudsLibrary /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages